# UnsafeNativeMethods exception with GroupPrincipal.getMembers()

Tags: .net-core, directoryservices

I recently started porting our .Net 4.6 web application to .Net Core 2.0 and am having some problems regarding the access to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

I want to access `GroupPrincipal.getMembers()` but keep getting an `UnsafeNativeMethods` exception:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods+IAds.GetInfoEx(object vProperties, int lnReserved)
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache(String[] propertyNames)
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.RangeRetriever.GetNextChunk()
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.RangeRetriever.MoveNext()
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.GetNextEnum()
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNextMemberEnum()
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
AspNetCore._Views_Groups_Show_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in Show.cshtml
+
    @foreach (var p in Model.GetMembers())
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

The code in the Show.cshtml:

```
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
@model GroupPrincipal

@foreach (var p in Model.GetMembers())
{
  ...
}
```

The exception:
`System.Exception: An operations error occurred.`

Already tried moving the code from the view into the controller and marking it with `unsafe` but that doesn't help either.

Code is already running as domain admin, can access all users etc. Just the method calls don't work.

What's the correct way to handle this?

Comment: You only show a stack trace, what is the exception?  What does the code look like?

Comment: thanks, added the details in the post. The exception doesn't give any hint. The code is a simple method access.

Comment: Just google the exception message, we have several existing Q+A that document this to be caused by a permission problem caused by impersonation.

Comment: Googled it many times in the last days, found those Q+A's and the App is already running as domain admin. It's exactly the same setup as in the old .Net-App.

Comment: I can also access users and all other stuff in AD. Just when calling a method there's the error.

Comment: These are very important details that belong in the question.  The more you tell us, the likelier that you'll get an answer that actually helps you.

Comment: ok, added more details. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems that I've found a solution/workaround:

I saw that it processes the principals and throws an exception after processing them.
So I just put the principals in another list and caught the exception.

The new list contains all principals and can be accessed without problems.

```cs
List<Principal> members = new List<Principal>();

try
{
    members.AddRange(group.GetMembers());
} 
catch (Exception)
{
    ; // do nothing
}
```

Must be a bug in the .NET core implementation of `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: I don't think this a .net core issue. I think this happens if the AD Member in the Group is Orphaned or the members cannot be resolved. [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Cleanup-orphan-ForeignSecur-22903124)